# Springboot scan parent entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, inheritance

I'm working on rest-api for an old application.

When I launch my service and I begin to use it I have this exception :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PersistentEntity must have an
> identifier property!

Indeed my object has not id field on it but on his parent.

```
@Entity
public class Object extends AbstractObject {
...
}

@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public abstract class AbstractObject {

    protected ObjectProperty<Long> id = new SerializableSimpleObjectProperty<>();

    public classAbstractObject () {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen")
    public Long getId() {
        return id!=null?id.get():null;
    }

    public ObjectProperty<Long> idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }
```

...
}

This is my controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/object")
public class ObjectController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectRepository objectRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public Object getObjects() {
        return this.objectRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path="/getByField", params = {"field"})
    public Object getByField(@QueryParam("field") String field) {
        return this.objectRepository.findByField(field);
    }
```

Dis I miss something ?

Thank you for you help  !

Comment: instead of getter method what if you annotate the id property directly?

`@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idgen") protected ObjectProperty<Long> id ; `

Comment: im not sure if an @ ID can be of type ObjectProperty<>, but try @ruhul hint first.

Comment: Instead of objectProperty try Long directly.

Comment: Thank you all
Indeed the problem was the ObjectProperty, but it's working on my client side with it and I don't understand why we don't have the same behavior.
Because for me, Hybernate should call the methode "Long getId()" and inside I can do what I want (and for the setter "void setId(Long id)") but seems not be the case...
Thank you for your help, I have removed this ObjectProperty for my Id and it's fine !